# Programming ATtiny10 with Arduino ( "ld.exe" errors)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arduino, compilation

## Issue

I am trying to compile a sketch in "Arduino IDE 1.8.9" for ATtiny10 and i am always getting these errors:

- **When** Using [**ATTiny10 Core**](https://github.com/vitasimek/attiny10core)

```
"C:\\Users\\gxous\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=attiny10 -o "C:\\Users\\gxous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_433979/testat10_nov26a.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\gxous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_433979\\sketch\\testat10_nov26a.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\gxous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_433979/core\\core.a" "-LC:\\Users\\gxous\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino_build_433979" -lm
c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find crtattiny10.o: No such file or directory

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/lib\libm.a when searching for -lm

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lm

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/lib\libm.a when searching for -lm

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lm

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/lib\libc.a when searching for -lc

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lc

c:/users/gxous/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lattiny10

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny10/9/5/4.
```

- **When** Using [**bitduino10**](https://make.kosakalab.com/make/electronic-work/arduino_tpi_en/)

```
...
same errors
...
Error compiling for board ATtiny10 (bitDuino10-arduinoTPI).
```

## Infos

- [ATtiny10 Dev Environment on Arduino IDE](https://make.kosakalab.com/make/electronic-work/arduino_tpi_en/)
- *`"file>preferences"`*

```
  https://kimio-kosaka.github.io/bitDuino10-arduinoTPI/package_bitDuino10-arduinoTPI_index.json
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vitasimek/attiny10core/master/package_attiny10core_index.json
```

## Outro

if i wasn't informative enough about the issue, please let me know

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

George

## UPDATE

What i actually did *(although not the solution you might expect)* , was just to install permanently an older version of Arduino IDE, as mentioned [here](https://make.kosakalab.com/make/electronic-work/arduino_tpi_en/) and used in [my project](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/ATtinyHearring) too.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/arduino.cc/forum/#!topic/developers/Ny82s7t11Vc

Comment: @Juraj thanks (: ! Do you have by any Chance any idea on how I could fix this issue instead of downgrading From 7.3.0 toolchain to an older one? or a way of switching between 7.3.0 and older versions (on arduino ide)?

Answer (score 2):

The linker is using the wrong multilib.  This can happen because you are supplying the linker with the wrong options, or because the installation is broken (or both).

First step in tracking down such issues is adding -v to the compiler driver's options (avr-gcc or avr-g++ in this case) to see which options are passed to the sub-processes.